# Selecting two attributes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to select 'language' and 'food' from an XML, using XSLT, that has elements like this:

```
  <item id="1">
    <language>Spanish</language>
    <food>Paella</food>
    <score>3.5</score>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <language>Italian</language>
    <food>Spagetthi</food>
    <score>3.5</score>
  </item>
```

I haved tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="language|food">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:value-of select="language, ';')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="food, ';')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I am looking for is like this:
Spanish;Paella,Italian;Spagetthi;

Comment: I see no "Italian" in your input - please see: [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you just match `item`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am sorry, that was just an example and I agree it was not clear. I meant in my first code-quote that there might be several items containing different kinds of languages and Foods. I will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: @Filburt if I do that it also includes the score

Comment: Which XSLT version are you using? `<xsl:value-of select="language, ';')"/>` is invalid in any version, and `<xsl:value-of select="(language, ';')"/>` can only work in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@michael.hor257k has very kindly provided with working code, but he didn't give you any indication of why your attempt was broken, so I fear it may not take you very far towards a better understanding of the concepts. Let's look at your attempt:

```
  <xsl:template match="language|food">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:value-of select="language, ';')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="food, ';')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

There are several reasons this can never work.

Firstly, you need to fix the missing parentheses in the `xsl:value-of` instructions. If you want to output the value of the language element followed by a semicolon, there are various ways of doing it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(language, ';')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="language"/>
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
```

or in XSLT 2.0 (or later)

```
<xsl:value-of select="language, ';'"/>
```

Second point: an expression like `select="language"` is short for `select="child::language"` - it selects the language element that is a child of the current (or 'context') node. Within xsl:template, the context node is the node matched by the match pattern. Your match pattern is `match="language|food"`. Neither of these has a child element called language or food, so your xsl:value-of instructions will select nothing.

Third point: your template rule is processing the children of the matched elements twice. First it uses `xsl:apply-templates` to process the children using pattern matching, and then it uses `xsl:value-of` to process them explicitly by name. Either technique works fine; using both together will usually give you duplicate output.

Comment: thank you alot! This really helped me understand what I am doing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input actually looks like this:

**XML**

```
<world>
  <item id="1">
    <language>Spanish</language>
    <food>Paella</food>
    <score>3.5</score>
  </item>
 <item id="2">
    <language>Italian</language>
    <food>Spagetthi</food>
    <score>3.5</score>
  </item>
</world>
```

you can use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/world">
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:value-of select="language"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="food"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="language"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="food"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

```
Spanish;Paella;Italian;Spagetthi;
```

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly and sorry for not getting back to you sooner.